# using the ADF server variables (querystring data)

Tags: java, ambient-data-framework

I notice that the ADF by puts a load of default content into the claim store.

i'm trying to extract the querystring values placed into them so i can modify them via my own ADF cartridge.

these values are stored in the following format:

> 2015-11-16 16:19:48,495 DEBUG ClaimStore - put:
>   uri=taf:request:parameters,
>   value={CONTENT_TYPE=[Ljava.lang.String;@3da776fa,
>   two=[Ljava.lang.String;@3d7436b5,
>   QUERY_STRING=[Ljava.lang.String;@18b3c498,
>   one=[Ljava.lang.String;@422fe3d3, three=[Ljava.lang.String;@56165397}

I'm wondering if there's some inbuilt tools to parse this data out and convert the string back to readable values... before i jump in and start coding it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ADF stores a couple of the **taf:request:parameters** entries as a HashMap<String,String[]>>. These are:

- CONTENT_LENGTH
- CONTENT_TYPE
- QUERY_STRING
- PATH_INFO

In addition, the ADF stores the HttpServletRequest parameter map in it's entirety on the claim as well, so given the following example query string:

```
?foo=1&bar=2
```

In total, you get the following easy way to get request parameters:

```
    final Map<String,?> requestParametersFromClaimStore = claimStore.get(WebClaims.REQUEST_PARAMETERS,HashMap.class);

    if (requestParametersFromClaimStore != null) {

        // get foo parameter
        String fooParam = (String) requestParametersFromClaimStore.get("foo");
        // get bar parameter
        String barParam = (String) requestParametersFromClaimStore.get("bar");

        // Get complete query string
        String[] queryStringArray = (String[]) requestParametersFromClaimStore.get("QUERY_STRING");
        String queryString = queryStringArray != null && queryStringArray.length > 0 ? queryStringArray[0] : "";

        // Repeat for CONTENT_LENGTH, CONTENT_TYPE and PATH_INFO
    }
```

Comment: no problem @johnwinter XXX

Answer (score 3):

I think this is returned as a `List<string>` object.

You may want to check how I do some of this claim reading on the [Context Engine Wrapper](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/TridionContextEngineWrapper/tree/master/Sdl.Tridion.Context).